# How to convert JSON Array to Java ArrayList object

Tags: java, arrays, json, arraylist

This is the result of my servlet in json Array that is converted to string using

```
 /*Converting Json Array to String*/
         StringWriter toStringF = new StringWriter();
         arrayFood.writeJSONString(toStringF);
         /*Printing Json Array - String*/
         response.getWriter().println(toStringF.toString());
```

The result shows

```
[{"Food":{"foodName":"Chicken Tenders","foodDescription":"Deep fried chicken tenders with rice","price":150.0,"foodID":59,"rating":5.0}},{"Food":{"foodName":"Roasted Duck\/Asado Rice","foodDescription":"Roasted duck with asado rice","price":210.0,"foodID":32,"rating":4.0}},{"Food":{"foodName":"Steamed Minced Beef Rice","foodDescription":"Steamed minced beef with rice","price":140.0,"foodID":40,"rating":4.0}},{"Food":{"foodName":"Buffalo Wings","foodDescription":"Deep fried chicken wings coated in hot sauce","price":160.0,"foodID":54,"rating":4.0}},{"Food":{"foodName":"H Burger","foodDescription":"The Hatchery's specialty burger","price":135.0,"foodID":58,"rating":4.0}}]
```

I tried to search the net on how to convert the jsonArrayStrings to arraylist of object but there are different kinds of codes and imports and right now I am totally confused which to use. It will help me a lot if there is a simpler way to do this.

I want to convert the above JsonArray Strings to an object.. something like the FoodName can be set into its properties like this one ex. food.FoodName(jsonObject.getString("FoodName"))..

```
ArrayList<Food> food = new ArrayList<Food>();
```

Comment: Try Jackson mapper https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/

Answer (score -1):

Refer this [site](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(yourJSONresponse);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
    list.add(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
}
```